# Python socket strange behavior

Tags: python, sockets, netcat

I can't understand why this code works fine,

```
echo as3333 | nc stat.ripe.net 43
```

but the equivalent code in Python returns nothing

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('stat.ripe.net', 43))
sock.send('as3333'.encode('utf-8'))
tmp = sock.recv(1024)
print(tmp.decode('utf-8')) #no bytes there
sock.close()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not exactly the same. You forgot the newline and `sendall`. Fixed code:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('stat.ripe.net', 43))
sock.sendall('as3333\r\n'.encode('utf-8'))

response = b''
while True:
    tmp = sock.recv(65536)
    if not tmp:
        break
    response += tmp

print(response.decode('utf-8'))
sock.close()
```

Comment: (it takes some time to gather the whole response).